# Running Unity CLI on Headless Linux to build open source project - license issue

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, travis-ci

How can I run Unity CLI on Linux to build my project without getting the dreaded "Failed to activate/update license" error. Why do I need a license to do a build from the command line? This works fine for Unity CLI on macOS and Windows.

Launching Unity from the UI and signing in once is not an option as I am trying to do this on Travis CI.

[Here's my .travis.yml file and related install + build scripts](https://github.com/bbodenmiller/ci-build/blob/680f682f7bef215e51602c5dd69980cb05c64c1b/.travis.yml) and [here's the failing build](https://travis-ci.org/bbodenmiller/ci-build/builds/212660304)

Answer (score 1):

The doc [Command line arguments](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) mentions serial, username and password. But they seem not in your build scripts.

Also try [the lastest build of Unity3D for linux](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/#post-2983106).
There is a fix in the lastest release (5.6.0b10):

> Fix "Manage License" UI regression

**UPDATE**

Just found [a post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/5-4-0p1-fails-to-launch-due-to-license.425277/#post-2943081) about your problem. Hope it helps.

> 1) Network issue - Some education users will have internal network and lack of internet access (can you verify if you can ping to https://core.cloud.unity3d.com/api/login on command line?).
>
> 2) To verify if it is a CACerts.pem issue, can you follow this code:
>   https://github.com/justin-zheng/travisbuildtest
>   CACerts.pem is included in the repository
>   Add the CACerts.pem to the Unity license folder (in the user's .local directory: ~/.local/share/unity3d/Certificates/)

Comment: But personal edition has no serial number? I tried passing in username and password [here](https://github.com/bbodenmiller/ci-build/blob/6d73a8cc7624317ad914bed8ebfeeae07f7cbf6b/Scripts/build.sh#L35) ([failing job](https://travis-ci.org/bbodenmiller/ci-build/jobs/212670675)) but didn't help. Tried latest beta [here](https://github.com/bbodenmiller/ci-build/blob/680f682f7bef215e51602c5dd69980cb05c64c1b/Scripts/install.sh#L52) ([failing job](https://travis-ci.org/bbodenmiller/ci-build/builds/212660304)) also no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/justin-zheng/travisbuildtest is an example on macOS, not Linux so that doesn't really help.

Comment: Just ran another build with curl and ping and no network issues reported: https://travis-ci.org/bbodenmiller/ci-build/jobs/213202362

Comment: @bbodenmiller did you find a solution? I just want to compile assetbundles on a server, I don't need any kind of licence but Unity requires that.
Your blog article does not seem to speak about licenses.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and use a license file following next steps.

Create license file:

`/opt/unity-editor-2018.3.0f2/Editor/Unity -batchmode -createManualActivationFile -logfile -nographics`

Go to https://license.unity3d.com/manual and upload ulf generated file

Use downloaded ulf file:

`/opt/unity-editor-2018.3.0f2/Editor/Unity -batchmode -manualLicenseFile Unity_v2018.x.ulf -logfile -nographics`

That's all